# What are the expected vibration frequencies in a co-axial rotor system with contra-rotating propellers?

Tags: helicopter, frequency, vibration, contra-rotating

I am trying to understand the frequency spectrum of a co-axial rotor system. Form now i have a RC helicopter with two sets of three gear systems arranged in parallel, The number of teeth are 7,23,27) respectively. The 2 input dc motors are running at 35K RPM which runs the rotors at approximately 2800 RPM because of the total gear ratio 12.47.

What I understand the frequency spectrum should have
-6 peaks of individual gears at there respective rpm's.
-2 peaks of Gear Mesh Frequency
-2 peaks of blade pass frequencies (rotor have 2 blades each total 4 blades in the RC helicopter.

Is there anything I am missing in this?